# "adviceDidNotMatch" warning when i try adding a new advice to an aspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj, aspect

I am trying to add a new advice to my aspectJ.

```
public aspect Aspect11 {

    pointcut namePC(String s, int i) : call (public String Simple.getName(String, int))&&args(s,i);

    pointcut getData(int j) : get(public int Simple.trial)&&args(j);

    after(String s, int i) : namePC(s, i) {
        // this is the advice
        System.out.println("Printing..." + s + "   " + i);
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.getSignature());
    }

    before(int j):getData(j)
    {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

In the code above, pointcut namePC() and its advice were already added. This was working as expected.

Following is my Simple.java

```
public class Simple {
private String name = "Aman";
String home;
int trial;
public String getName(String s, int i) {

    System.out.println("Hi in getName()" + s + "   " + i);
    return name;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Simple simple = new Simple();
    simple.trial=8;
    System.out.println("AA" + simple.getName("In Simple", 1));
}
```

}

When i try adding the new point cut and its advice : getData(), i am getting a warning : "advice defined in Aspect11 has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]"
Am new to aspectJ and not getting a way to sort this out!!

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your edited version still does not work for two reasons:

- `Simple.trial` is not `public` as your pointcut states.
- Why should a `get()` pointcut match if you never read from the member? In your code there is only an assignment, i.e. a `set()` pointcut would match.

Try this:

```
public class Simple {
    private String name = "Aman";
    private int trial;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Simple simple = new Simple();
        simple.trial = 8;
        System.out.println(simple.getName("foo", 1));
    }

    public String getName(String s, int i) {
        System.out.println("getName(" + s + ", " + i + ")");
        return name;
    }
}

public aspect Aspect11 {
    pointcut namePC(String s, int i) :
        call (public String Simple.getName(String, int)) && args(s,i);

    pointcut setData(int j) :
        set(int Simple.trial) && args(j);

    after(String s, int i) : namePC(s, i) {
        System.out.println("namePC: " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature());
    }

    before(int j) : setData(j) {
        System.out.println("setData: " + j);
    }
}
```